# Making color of Sprite Darker or Lighter in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

Is there any way to make a Sprite darker or lighter in AndEngine?
I dont want to use the Alpha thing.

Please reply if its is possible.
Thanks

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

sprite.setColor(pRed, pGreen, pBlue, pAlpha) might be useful. What is the problem with using alpha?

Comment: setColor will actually change the color.
Alpha will make it transparent.
I have a chocolate cake i want to show it in three ways.
Half Cooked, Full Baked and Burnt. I want to use one image for this purpose. Thats why I asked here about the solution.